# What will happen if Quartz jobs do not throw JobExecutionException?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have seen code where we have Quartz jobs which do not throw `JobExecutionException` exception. In most of the cases, even unchecked exceptions are not being handled.

Is that a good practice? What are we missing by not raising `JobExecutionException` exception? What will be the impact to Quartz scheduler?

Context:
We have lots of Quartz scheduler jobs (more than 30). None of them throws or handle `JobExecutionException`.

Comment: It would help if you provided some context for your unhandled exceptions. As I'm sure you know, in general, all possible exceptions should be handled, so unless you're seeing unhandled exceptions in example code, it's bad practice.

Comment: @MarsAtomic: What is the additional info you need?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner. Are you seeing unhandled exceptions in production code, written by a competent programmer, or are you seeing them in example code? It's really hard to answer your question without knowing exactly what you're seeing -- providing code provides the context for answering your question.

Comment: @MarsAtomic: Unhandled exceptions are not issue. My question is that what will happen if I do not rethrow them as `JobExecutionException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer once I studies the code of `quartz-core`. As per [line](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/ce1650f2bd23166b913a342a73c5c62e30d73632/quartz-core/src/main/java/org/quartz/core/JobRunShell.java#L218), it treats those exception as `JobExecutionException` with `refire` to false. It will behave as if the code is throwing `JobExceutionException` with no immediately refire.

With this, if there are next instances available, next instances will be fired up on their schedule.